# how to fix jquery error in rails for blue-imp gallery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am having problem in showing images in popup window.

view page

```
<div class="col-md-offset-1">
  <div class='row'><br/>
    <div id ="links">
  <% @cable_photos.each_with_index do |cable_photo, i| %>
  <% i += 1 %>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <label>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
      <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_cable_photo_path(cable_photo), class: 'btn btn-default btn-xs' %>
      <%= link_to cable_photo, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn btn-danger btn-xs' do %>
      <i class='icon icon-remove'></i>
      <% end %>
      </label>
      <%= link_to   cable_photo.avatar.url  do %>
      <%= image_tag cable_photo.avatar.url(:medium), class: "img-thumbnail" ,style: "height: 140px; width:  250px;" %>
      <% end %>
      <p style="text-align:center;"><b><%= cable_photo.address %></b></p><br/>
    </div>
    <% if (i%5) == 0 %>
    <div class='row'></div>
    <% end %>  
    <% end %>        
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery">
<div class="slides"></div>
<h3 class="title"></h3>
<a class="prev">‹</a>
<a class="next">›</a>
<a class="close">×</a>
<a class="play-pause"></a>
<ol class="indicator"></ol>
</div>
```

Script

```
document.getElementById('links').onclick = function (event) {
  event = event || window.event;
  var target = event.target || event.srcElement,
    link = target.src ? target.parentNode : target,
    options = {index: link, event: event},
    links = this.getElementsByTagName('a');
  blueimp.Gallery(links, options);
};
```

Images are viewable in popup window. but it takes edit and destroy link also. so, problem in **links = this.getElementByTagName("a");** 
Within in the link div I have to show to image with edit and delete link also.

So, when I click edit button it won't redirect to edit page of image. instead of that it try to show edit as image in popup window. because of jquery getElementByTagName.

Please help me. How to slove this issue.

Comment: `return false ` not used in for click event

Comment: `getElementByTagName` is [pure JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName), not JQuery

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do this:

```
document.getElementById('links').onclick = function (event) {
  event = event || window.event;
  var target = event.target || event.srcElement,
    link = target.src ? target.parentNode : target,
    options = {index: link, event: event},
    links = this.getElementsByTagName('a');
  blueimp.Gallery(links, options);

  //Stops default link "action" happening on current page
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
};
```

Comment: When I click Edit button it won't redirect to edit page of image. instead of that it showing image in popup window.